# Organization Profile - which Organization is the info going to get attached to?

Tags: profile, forms, organization

I've created a profile specifically for organizations so that I can collect additional data about them. But I'm sure I'm missing something.

When I click on Use (Create Mode) it shows me a form with all of the fields that I've added to the profile. Given that, how do I know where the data inputted into the profile's fields gets attached to - does it get attached to an organization? If it does, how does it do that (without specifying the organization)? If not, how do I attach it to an organization - does the organization name or similar field need to be included in the profile?

I simply find it weird that I can open Use (Create Mode) for organization profiles (and hit save) without knowing where the data from a profile will be attached to.

Answer (score 1):

In create mode, it will create a contact with no name if you don't have a name field.

Comment: Therefore add Org Name field.